# How to stop AppInsights flattening array of strings from a simple http post

Tags: c++, json, azure-application-insights

I am trying to send data to AppInsights from cpp as a simple piece of json. But, AppInsights insists of flattening my array of strings into a comma separated string.

For example, if the post body is this:

```
{
    "data": {
        "baseData": {
            "name": "UWMLicensing",
            "properties": {
                "myValues": ["1", "2"]
            },
            "ver": "2"
        },
        "baseType": "EventData"
    },
    "iKey": "<iKey>",
    "name": "Event",
    "time": "2021-09-15T17:00:16Z"
}
```

This arrives in AppInsights as a customEvent with the customDimensions set to the `myValues` property. However, the customDimensions data is set to:

```
{"myValues": "1, 2"}
```

I'd like AppInsights to leave the array alone and for the customDimensions be set to:

```
{"myValues": ["1", "2"]}
```

How can I convince AppInsights to not flatten my array and leave the data as it was?

My test app uses libcurl:

```
int main(void)
{
    CURL *curl;

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        const char *line = 
            "{"
                "\"data\": {"
                    "\"baseData\": {"
                        "\"name\": \"UWMLicensing\","
                        "\"properties\": {"
                        "\"array\": [\"1\", \"2\"]"
                        "},"
                        "\"ver\": \"2\""
                    "},"
                    "\"baseType\": \"EventData\""
                "},"
                "\"iKey\": \"<YOUR_INSTRUMENTATION_KEY>\","
                "\"name\": \"Event\","
                "\"time\": \"%s\""
            "}";

        char json[255];
        sprintf_s(json, 255, line, getTime().c_str());

        struct curl_slist *list = NULL;
        list = curl_slist_append(list, "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://dc.services.visualstudio.com/v2/track");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, list);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json);

        curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_slist_free_all(list);

        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }

    curl_global_cleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you use string as a log in app insights instead of using it as an Array as because internally in app insights all values provided by default will be string.

Answer (score 0):

Posting the comment as an answer to help other community members

In the below code the string what you are using use it as a log in the application insights instead of using it as an array as because the strings are the default values of application insights internally.

```cpp
int main(void)
{
    CURL *curl;

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        const char *line = 
            "{"
                "\"data\": {"
                    "\"baseData\": {"
                        "\"name\": \"UWMLicensing\","
                        "\"properties\": {"
                        "\"array\": [\"1\", \"2\"]"
                        "},"
                        "\"ver\": \"2\""
                    "},"
                    "\"baseType\": \"EventData\""
                "},"
                "\"iKey\": \"<YOUR_INSTRUMENTATION_KEY>\","
                "\"name\": \"Event\","
                "\"time\": \"%s\""
            "}";

        char json[255];
        sprintf_s(json, 255, line, getTime().c_str());

        struct curl_slist *list = NULL;
        list = curl_slist_append(list, "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://dc.services.visualstudio.com/v2/track");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, list);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json);

        curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_slist_free_all(list);

        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }

    curl_global_cleanup();

    return 0;
}
```